# What Madoka Magica poster is this?

Tags: madoka-magica, gamers

Episode 4 of *Gamers!* has a scene where two characters go to an arcade.

[image: Gamers! episode 4, 14:06]

Off to the right side of the scene is a poster that is unmistakably from *Madoka Magica*:

[image: meguca]

I consider myself something of a fan of *Madoka Magica*, but I don't think I've ever seen this poster. What, specifically, is this a poster for? One of the video games?

Answer (score 2):

Given the characters are at an arcade and the assuming the shape in the bottom right is an arcade cabinet I believe the poster is trying to represent Madoka Magicard Battle, a card battling game based on the series and films.

I have not been able to find a poster, though the text and annotated images make it look more like a magazine or advert page than a movie poster.

The key art may also be images put together from individual shots as no key art has the group of five in that order.

My best guess that if this is based on an existing poster, it is for the Madoka Arcade card game and is an instructional poster designed to be displayed outside the arcade itself.